No Printer connection
Since upgrading to 24.04 from 22.24 have been unable to print documents on Epson XP 2200 through WiFi or cable. However it will print the Network Connection Sheet (NCS) and images from its scanner but the passwords shown on the NCS have no effect . What can be done?
